# undefined method `set' for nil:NilClass in Rails even though similar code works in irb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, prometheus

The following code works fine in IRB (Interactive Ruby Shell):
require 'prometheus/client'

```
prometheus = Prometheus::Client.registry
begin
  @requests = prometheus.gauge(:demo, 'Random number selected for this users turn.')
rescue Prometheus::Client::Registry::AlreadyRegisteredError => e
end
@requests.set({name: "test"}, 123)
test =  @requests.get name: "test"
    puts 'output: ' + test.to_s
```

2.4.0 :018 > load 'test.rb'
output: 123.0
 => true
2.4.0 :019 >

However, when I put the same code into my Ruby on Rails controller, the second time the user uses the application, the following error is returned:
undefined method `set' for nil:NilClass

Can someone tell me when I'm doing wrong? Thank you.

```
require 'prometheus/client'

class RandomnumbersController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @randomnumbers = Randomnumber.order('number DESC').limit(8)
    @counter = 0
  end

  def show
    @randomnumber = Randomnumber.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
  end

  def create
    @randomnumber = Randomnumber.new(randomnumber_params)

    prometheus = Prometheus::Client.registry
    begin
      @requests = prometheus.gauge(:demo, 'Random number selected for this users turn.')
    rescue Prometheus::Client::Registry::AlreadyRegisteredError => e
    end
    @requests.set({name: "test"}, 123)
    test =  @requests.get name: "test"

    @randomnumber.save
    redirect_to @randomnumber
  end

  private
  def randomnumber_params
    params.require(:randomnumber).permit(:name, :number)
  end
end
```

Comment: inside `rescue ... end` block you can write `puts e` to see if a `Prometheus::Client::Registry::AlreadyRegisteredError` is caught

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because there is no `@requests` for `:demo` argument.

When ORM cannot find any info in db it returns `nil` (`NilClass`)

and You're trying to do:

```
@requests.set({name: "test"}, 123)
```

it's interpreted like:

```
nil.set({name: "test"}, 123)
```

- why it's causes this issue in second time?
- cuz Your code changes `@requests` `name` attribute to be `test` and seems like `:demo` is not `test` or maybe in another part of Your app You're replacing/deleting data in database that makes: `@requests = prometheus.gauge(:demo, 'Random number selected for this users turn.')` to return `nil`

**Solution:**

in code level add this fixes to avoid such unpredictable situations (check for `nil`) :

```
unless @requests.nil?
  @requests.set({name: "test"}, 123)
  test =  @requests.get name: "test"
end
```